# Wordpress site not fully moved

Tags: php, wordpress

I have moved a wordpress site from /wordpress/ to / and it has worked except for the header navigation bar.

http://vashonschoolsfoundation.org/thank-you/annual-report/

If you click on of the top links (not one of the dropdown links), it takes you to a /wordpress/ url.

IE: if you click Thank you, it should take you here,

http://vashonschoolsfoundation.org/thank-you/annual-report/

but instead it takes you here:

http://vashonschoolsfoundation.org/wordpress/thank-you/annual-report/

The correct url (without /wordpress) works, but it isn't the one getting linked to.

All the submenu links work fine.

How can I fix this?

Note: when you hover over the top links, they say they will take you to the right links (in the url preview browser feature in most browsers), but they take you to the wrong (/wordpress) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that only two top navigation links redirects to /wordpress/ ('Thank You' and 'Contribute'). 'About' and 'Contact us' works correctly.
When clicking on 'Contribute' server sends Location header - Location:http://vashonschoolsfoundation.org/wordpress/contribute/give-today/

This header is set somewhere in you code or options that are saved in database. I don't think that the problem in database, because in this case all links will be broken.
Try to disable all plugins, switch to default theme and check the links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the "site address" in your Wordpress general settings?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just move the files one directory up? Because there is more to it than just that. I've used [these detailed instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) a few times to move Wordpress installations.

Answer (score 0):

Dump your wordpress DB and then search replace old URL from the dump and then drop your current db and then import the corrected one.

Do you still have an wordpress under /wordpress/ folder?

Comment: also, in your wp-config.php file. put the following lines:
    `define(WP_SITEURL,'http://vashonschoolsfoundation.org/');`
    `define(WP_HOME,'http://vashonschoolsfoundation.org/');`

Comment: these lines are aleady there.

Comment: Did you cleanup the database as I said?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make two changes in your database table `wp_options`

All you have to do is change the `option_value` field to the correct URL for the records with `option_name=’siteurl‘` or `option_name=’home‘`.

Read the instructions in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).